# Node server not reachable from outside

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am playing with a small node server application.I have hosted it in AWS Lightsail's ubuntu instance. It is reachable from local browser like http://localhost:4201/

[image]

but when I try to access it from remote, it is unreachable.

[image]

In aws instance's network config I have opened traffic for all ports

[image]

I have cleared all rules from iptables as well. I am able to reach http port 80 and ping successfully. But no luck with node server, what am I missing? Is there a special way to enable traffic to node server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I debugged it, basically in server.ts

I had bound it to localhost so it won't accept request from outside

```
app.listen(4201, '127.0.0.1', function () {
    console.log('Server Listening on 0.0.0.0:4201');
});
```

changed it to `0.0.0.0`

```
app.listen(4201, '0.0.0.0', function () {
    console.log('Server Listening on 0.0.0.0:4201');
});
```

And now it is accessible from everywhere.